# Which PayPal API for variable billing

Tags: paypal

I have a site that bills variable monthly amounts based on the subscriber's usage (typically $3 to $60). Currently, the 200 or so subscribers set up a monthly PP subscription that may or may not match their usage. I would probably use IPN to collect that info, but currently do it by hand.

I would like to use an API to request and receive the exact monthly amount. Which API? I have read elsewhere that Adaptive Payments may be the one to use, but is that appropriate/accessible to my business size?

Additionally, where would I post a request for a programmer for such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to utilize [Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/) for that.

Basically, you setup a billing agreement with the user an then you can use the Billing Agreement ID that you get back with the [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) API any time in the future to process any amount necessary without further approval.

So you'll need to create your own system to automatically process payments on a daily basis as necessary, but this method will allow you to handle variable amounts.

If you're using Payments Pro you can do the same thing, but you don't do a "billing agreement".  What you can do instead is run a $0 authorization, and then you would use the transaction ID you get back from that in the DoReferenceTransaction request instead of a Billing Agreement ID.

Comment: This looks interesting. I don't have a cart, as referenced in the API, and am not using Pro, but I assume the method will still work? Is this enough information for me to post a job request somewhere to hire some programmer?

Comment: It would be for a programmer who knows PayPal (or general payment processor standards) well...like me.  ;)

Comment: I'm from the future. Does this method work for now (2019)?

Comment: Yes, it would still work, but it's all Classic API stuff, so you would need to make sure your account is setup for that.